# Output with greatest common factor

Tags: c++, cout

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int gcf(int a, int b);

int main() {
  int a = 0, b = 0;

  while (1) {
    cin >> a;

    if (a == 0)
      break;

    cin >> b;
    cout << "GCF = " gcf(a, b) << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}

int gcf(int a, int b) {
  if (a % b == 0)
    return b;
  else
    return gcf(b, a % b);
}
```

So ,my question is: How could I make the program show all steps of the greatest common factor? For example, if `a` is 300 and `b` is 500,the program should show the steps like this:

> GCF(300,500)=>
>     GCF(500,300)=>
>     GCF(300,200)=>
>     GCF(200,100)=>
>     GCF=100

Comment: Why `c#`, `android` and `c` tags?

Comment: Your code is already prepared to this modification, because the implementation is recursive. All you need to do is to add a line that prints `a` and `b` at the beginning of your `gcf` implementation.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int gcf(int a, int b);

int main() {
int a = 0, b = 0;

while (1) {
 cin >> a;

if (a == 0)
break;

cin >> b;
cout<<"GCF("<<a<<","<<b<<")=>";
cout<<gcf(a,b);
}

return 0;
```

}

```
int gcf(int a, int b) {
if (a % b == 0)
return b;
else
return gcf(b, a % b);
}
```